# Querying data from influxdb and storing it into a measurement (table)

Tags: mysql, aggregate, influxdb, querying

I'm new to using InfluxDB and I have what I think is a relatively simple question that I cannot find the answer to. How can I query data from an existing measurement and write that data into another measurement, while storing the name of the measurement where that data came from?

For example, say I had the measurement

> name: temperature
>
> time | external | internal |  machine
>
> 100  |     25    |      40      | unit42

Is there a way I could grab some of that data and the measurement name and put it into a new table? Like this:

> name: aggregate table
>
> time |  measurment |    external  |  machine
>
> 100 |   temperature  | 25          | unit42

to be clear, I've looked up the into method, but I can't find a way to also store the name of the measurement
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no way to turn a `measurement` name into a `tag` or `field` using a query. It's possible that you could use another tool like [kapacitor](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor) to do what you're trying to do.

That being said, typically the aggregate table is given the same name as the original table, but in a different `retention policy`. For example

```
$ influx
> create database tempdb
> use tempdb
Using database tempdb
> create retention policy my_rp on tempdb duration 0s replication 1
> insert temperature,machine=unit24 external=100,internal=40
> SELECT mean(internal) as internal, mean(external) as external INTO tempdb.my_rp.temperature FROM temperature GROUP BY *
name: result
------------
time    written
0       1
> SELECT * FROM tempdb.my_rp.temperature
name: temperature
-----------------
time    external    internal    machine
0       100         40          unit24
```

This way you still maintain the name, but the measurement is scoped to another retention policy.